# AEM Query Builder Multiple Values of Property

Tags: aem, query-builder

In AEM Query Builder, how can i query multiple value possibilities of a property

```
Predicate r1= new Predicate("property");
                r1.set("property", String.format("@jcr:content/cq:%s", "template"));
                r1.set("operation", "equals");
                r1.set("value", "/some/value1/text1");
                predicates.add(r1);
Predicate r2= new Predicate("property");
                r2.set("property", String.format("@jcr:content/cq:%s", "template"));
                r2.set("operation", "equals");
                r2.set("value", "/some/value2/sometext/text2");
                predicates.add(r2);
Predicate r3= new Predicate("property");
                r3.set("property", String.format("@jcr:content/cq:%s", "template"));
                r3.set("operation", "equals");
                r3.set("value", "/some/value3/sometext/anothertext/text3");
                predicates.add(r3);
```

Is there  a simpler way to query properyx.value=value1 or  properyx.value=value2 etc or propertyx.value in (value1,value2,value3,...)

Comment: Did you try using `r1.set("1_value", "/some/value1/text1"); r1.set("2_value", "/some/value2/sometext/text2"); r1.set("3_value", "/some/value3/sometext/anothertext/text3");`?

Comment: will it consider as "or" or "and"

Comment: It is an `or` unless you specify it as an `and`. At least that s what the generated query looks like using the query builder tool.

Comment: you are right i just validated it.. for AND we have to exclusively mention it.. thanks